# Can not display background-image in laravel

Tags: laravel

please help me! In `resources/views/welcome.bale.php:`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
<div class="factarea overlay">
    <h2>Facts that Make us Unique</h2>
</div>
```

In public folder: `css/style.css`

```css
.factarea {background-image: url(../img/website.jpg);}
```

**public/img/website.jpg**  location

Answer (score 1):

I hope the below line will help you to resolve this issue.

You can try this.

- background-image: url("/img/website.jpg");

You can try with another way like in-line css and check what we getting the image or not. so we can easily find the correct path.

Thanks

Comment: You can try with .factarea {background-image: url(./img/website.jpg);}

Comment: Happy to help you. @KumoMit

Answer (score 0):

use root path

```css
.factarea {background-image: url(/img/website.jpg);}
```

like this then

`websiteurl/img/website.jpg` will work here

`websiteurl/public/img/website.jpg` will not work only pretty url will work

so in order to work in `public` url as well you have to add inline css

which is

```php
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/style.css')}}">
<div class="factarea overlay" style="background-image: url({{ asset('img/website.jpg') }})">
    <h2>Facts that Make us Unique</h2>
</div>
```